# Apache Camel, SOAP/CXF client request exchange error

Tags: java, web-services, soap, apache-camel

I'm trying to build simple Camel route to public webservice,

http://wsf.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/Weather.asmx

I'm using latest Camel with Spring, CXF, SOAP and Java Config Modules.

Here's my CxfEndpoint :

```html
    @Bean(name = "testCxfBean")
    public CxfEndpoint createTestEndpoint() throws ClassNotFoundException {

        CxfEndpoint endpoint = new CxfEndpoint();

        endpoint.setAddress("http://wsf.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/Weather.asmx");
        endpoint.setWsdlURL("http://wsf.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/Weather.asmx?WSDL");
        endpoint.setEndpointNameString("WeatherSoap");
        endpoint.setServiceNameString("Weather");

        return endpoint;
    }
```

And here is my route :

```html
@Component
public class TestCXFRoute extends RouteBuilder {

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {

        SoapJaxbDataFormat dataFormat = new SoapJaxbDataFormat("com.cdyne.ws.weatherws", new ServiceInterfaceStrategy(
                WeatherSoap.class, true));
   
        from("timer:testTimer?period=5000").process(new Processor() {

            @Override
            public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                exchange.getIn().setBody(new GetWeatherInformation());
            }
        }).setHeader("operationName", constant("GetWeatherInformation")).marshal(dataFormat)
                .to("cxf:testCxfBean?serviceClass=com.cdyne.ws.weatherws.WeatherSoap").log("level:info");
    }

}
```

What I'm trying to do here is query weather information every 5 seconds, using GetWeatherInformation operation, marshalling relevant object, and simply logging result.

However I'm getting such error :

```html
Exchange[
 Id                  ID-darkstar-dev-39021-1423838783518-0-4
 ExchangePattern     InOnly
 Headers             {breadcrumbId=ID-darkstar-dev-39021-1423838783518-0-3, CamelRedelivered=false, CamelRedeliveryCounter=0, firedTime=Fri Feb 13 15:46:31 CET 2015, operationName=GetWeatherInformation}
 BodyType            byte[]
 Body                <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><ns2:Envelope xmlns:ns2="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns3="http://ws.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/">    <ns2:Body>        <ns3:GetWeatherInformation/>    </ns2:Body></ns2:Envelope>
]

Stacktrace
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Get the wrong parameter size to invoke the out service, Expect size 0, Parameter size 252. Please check if the message body matches the CXFEndpoint POJO Dataformat request.
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: It looks you are using SOAP data format and camel-cxf endpoint at the same time. Can you just choice one of them to create the soap request?

Comment: I tried using only SOAP and everything worked, thanks!